# QGIS OS grid overlay

Tags: qgis, ordnance-survey, united-kingdom

I'm totally new to GIS.  However, I've proudly managed to create a map, which is correctly geo-referenced with a Great Britain Ordnance Survey (OS) background (streetview level) and I've added some point data.

How do I create or import a layer with the OS grid lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the OS Grids here

https://github.com/charlesroper/OSGB_Grids

Download the shapefiles and then load them in

You will probably need to adjust the styling and turn on labelling using the tile name as a text label