# Which equal-area projection to use for UK?

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, united-kingdom

I have a bunch of UK polygons that are saved in my PostGIS database as WGS84 projection. I would like to calculate the area of these polygons using `st_area`.

According to [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20054/what-is-most-accurate-coordinate-system-for-calculating-areas-of-polygons) I can save these polygons in any equal-area projection to do this. Is it really true that I can use any equal-area projection? For example, if I save them in US National Atlas Equal area (SRID 2163) will that work?

In any case, is there a UK-focussed equal area projection that it would be most appropriate to use?

Comment: The most common European Project (EU, EC Official) is Lambert azimuthal equal-area projection http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_azimuthal_equal-area_projection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could calculate [ST_Area](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Area.html) on a geography type. Since you have data with WGS84 (SRID=4326), you can add a simple geography cast, e.g.

```
SELECT ST_Area(geom::geography)
```

which will return area in m² on a curved surface (sphereoid by default). This should be pretty close to the true surface area, without requiring any projection.

---

It would be interesting to see how the areas compares to data projected on [EPSG:27700](http://epsg.io/27700), which is a Transverse Mercator based national projection for the UK. More info on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordnance_Survey_National_Grid) and [The Ordnance Survey website](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/support/the-national-grid.html).

Comment: Yes, I would be interested to see that too, seeing as I mostly work in 27700.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer EPSG:3035. The ESRI codes might not be available on all platforms:

[image]

EPSG:2163 has a different lon_0 leading to a distortion of the map:

[image]

Comment: Out of interest, how did you generate these images?

Comment: @Richard with QGIS. The coastline is from Natural Earth, and the grid from http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79680/qgis-os-grid-overlay

Answer (score 1):

Actually it would work as both are about ~~~~ the same latitiude but use the Euro version **http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/102013/**